# Adding items to list from user input and printing list out to console

Tags: c#, list

I'm making a simple console-program. This program is supposed to give the user a console-menu that will give you three choices: To add an employee to a list, remove an employee from the list, and then to exit. I am trying to create a list that will add different users to the list after they have been initialized by user input. After that I want to print the list to console, but the list wont hold on to any input. If anyone has a clue whats wrong, please tell me! Also, I am fairly new to coding, so extensive explanations are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
using Employees;

namespace Inheritance
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool keepRunning = true;
            while (keepRunning)
            {
                List<Employee> EmployeesList = new List<Employee>();

                 void AddToList(Employee employee)
                {
                    EmployeesList.Add(employee);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("TIFFANYS & CO - PRIVATE PROGRAM TM\nPress the number of the action you want to pursue, and press [ENTER].\n1) Add an Employee\n2) Delete an Employee\n3) Exit");
                var menuChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (menuChoice)
                {
                    case 0:
                        foreach (Employee item in EmployeesList)                    
                        {                                                    
                            Console.WriteLine(item.firstName + " " + item.lastName + " " + item.salary);

                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("a) Add a Manager\nb) Add an Engineer\nc) Add a Researcher");
                        var menuChoice1 = Console.ReadLine();

                        switch (menuChoice1)
                        {
                            case "a":


                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the first name of the manager and press [ENTER]:");
                                string managerFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the last name of the manager and press [ENTER]:");
                                string managerLastName = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the salary of the manager and press [ENTER]:");
                                int managerSalary = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in how many meetings the manager will attend weekly and press [ENTER]:");
                                int managerMeetings = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in how many vacation-weeks the manager has annually and press [ENTER]:");
                                int managerVacationWeeks = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                                Manager manager = new(managerFirstName, managerLastName, managerSalary, managerMeetings, managerVacationWeeks);
                                EmployeesList.Add(manager);
                                foreach (var employee in EmployeesList)

                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(employee);
                                }

                                break;

                            case "b":


                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the first name of the engineer and press [ENTER]:");
                                string engineerFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the last name of the engineer and press [ENTER]:");
                                string engineerLastName = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the salary of the engineer and press [ENTER]:");
                                int engineerSalary = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                //Console.WriteLine("Is the engineer able to use C#? If yes, type [yes] and press [ENTER]. If no, type [no] and press [ENTER]:");
                                //string cSkill = Console.ReadLine();
                                //if (cSkill == "yes")
                                //{
                                //    engineer.cSharpSkill = true;
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                //    engineer.cSharpSkill = false;
                                //}
                                Console.WriteLine("How many years of experience does the engineer have? Type the number of years and press [ENTER]:");
                                int engineerExperience = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.WriteLine("What kind of engineering is the engineers field? Please write their field and press [ENTER]:");
                                string engineerField = Console.ReadLine();

                                Engineer engineer = new(engineerFirstName, engineerLastName, engineerSalary, engineerExperience, engineerField);

                                EmployeesList.Add(engineer);

                                break;

                            case "c":


                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the first name of the researcher and press [ENTER]:");
                                string researcherFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the last name of the researcher and press [ENTER]:");
                                string researcherLastName = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("Please type in the salary of the researcher and press [ENTER]:");
                                int researcherSalary = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.WriteLine("What university did the researcher get their Doctorate? Please type in the name of the university and press [ENTER]:");
                                string researcherUniversity = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("What was the thesis statement of the researchers doctorate? Please type in the thesis question and press [ENTER]:");
                                string researcherThesis = Console.ReadLine();
                                Researcher researcher = new(researcherFirstName, researcherLastName, researcherSalary, researcherUniversity, researcherThesis);

                                EmployeesList.Add(researcher);
                                break;
                        }

                        break;

                    case 2:

                        Console.WriteLine("What is the last name of the engineer to be deleted?");
                        string toDeleteLastName = Console.ReadLine();
                        Employee employeeToBeDeleted = EmployeesList.Find(e => e.lastName == toDeleteLastName);
                        if (employeeToBeDeleted != null)
                            EmployeesList.Remove(employeeToBeDeleted);
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine($"Could not find {employeeToBeDeleted}");
                        break;


                    case 3:
                        keepRunning = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a library installed via NuGet, [Spectre.Console](https://spectreconsole.net/) which makes life easier if you understand how to work with simple classes.

Once the Spectre.Console package has been installed you need the following `using` statement `using Spectre.Console;` for all classes. In regard to classes I only did three properties for the Employee model, you need to add the remaining properties if interest in this solution. If you get stuck, see [full source](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/console-apps/tree/master/MenuConsoleAppBasic) but for learning try not to use that code.

Start off with a model/class which represents menu items

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Text;

}
```

Create a class for presenting the menu

```
public class MenuOperations
{
    public static SelectionPrompt<MenuItem> MainMenu()
    {
        SelectionPrompt<MenuItem> menu = new()
        {
            HighlightStyle = new Style(
                Color.DodgerBlue1, 
                Color.Black, 
                Decoration.None)
        };

        menu.Title("Select an [B]option[/]");
        menu.AddChoices(new List<MenuItem>()
        {
            new MenuItem() {Id = 0, Text = "List employees"},
            new MenuItem() {Id = 1, Text = "Add manager"},
            new MenuItem() {Id = 2, Text = "Add Engineer"},
            new MenuItem() {Id = 3, Text = "Delete"},
            new MenuItem() {Id = -1, Text = "Exit"},
        });

        return menu;
    }
}
```

Main code in Program.cs. Following this pattern there is a clear cut path to handling various operations and exiting.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();

        List<Employee> EmployeesList = new List<Employee>();

        while (menuItem.Id > -1)
        {

            AnsiConsole.Clear();
            menuItem = AnsiConsole.Prompt(MenuOperations.MainMenu());
            switch (menuItem.Id)
            {
                case 0:
                    Operations.List(EmployeesList);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Add manager");
                    EmployeesList.Add(Operations.AddEmployee());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Add Engineer");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Delete");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get an idea how to handle adding a new item and listing items in the list the following code shows how.

- First and last name can not be empty else the prompt stays there. You can add a validation message (see the docs)
- Salary must be a double

With the above in mind you have some simple validation.

```
public class Operations
{

    public static Employee AddEmployee()
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee
        {
            FirstName = GetFirstName(),
            LastName = GetLastName(),
            Salary = GetSalary()
        };

        return employee;
    }

    public static string GetFirstName() =>
        AnsiConsole.Prompt(
            new TextPrompt<string>("[white]First name[/]?")
                .PromptStyle("yellow")
                .ValidationErrorMessage("[red]Please enter your first name[/]"));

    public static string GetLastName() =>
        AnsiConsole.Prompt(
            new TextPrompt<string>("[white]Last name[/]?")
                .PromptStyle("yellow")
                .ValidationErrorMessage("[red]Please enter your last name[/]"));

    public static double GetSalary() =>
        AnsiConsole.Prompt(
            new TextPrompt<double>("[white]Salary[/]?")
                .PromptStyle("yellow")
                .ValidationErrorMessage("[red]Please enter salary (numbers only)[/]"));

    public static void List(List<Employee> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            AnsiConsole.MarkupLine("Nothing is list, press [b]ENTER[/] to return to menu");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }

        var table = new Table()
            .RoundedBorder()
            .AddColumn("[b]First[/]")
            .AddColumn("[b]Last[/]")
            .AddColumn("[b]Salary[/]")
            .Alignment(Justify.Center)
            .BorderColor(Color.LightSlateGrey)
            .Title("[yellow]Employee list[/]");

        foreach (var employee in list)
        {
            table.AddRow(employee.FirstName, employee.LastName, employee.Salary.ToString("C"));
        }

        AnsiConsole.Write(table);
        AnsiConsole.MarkupLine("Press [b]ENTER[/] to return to menu");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Some screenshots

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the loop setup this way:

```
while (keepRunning)
{
    List<Employee> EmployeesList = new List<Employee>();
```

So every time you loop you delete the list of employees and get a new one. Try swapping the order:

```
List<Employee> EmployeesList = new List<Employee>();
while (keepRunning)
{
```

This way you start your program with a fresh employee list and use that same list while your program is running.

Comment: My case "0" still returns an empty list. I cant seem to find the bug.

Comment: @ayoubzann Returns an empty list after you add people? What does it do when you add a manager? Have you stepped through it with a debugger?